# React - TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined when i try to inject a function

Tags: reactjs

I define a function in my main class:

```
handleArticleUpdate(codice){
alert(codice);
//this.setState({codice_articolo: codice});
}
```

And i'm trying to inject it in my component:

```
<MainGrid onArticleChanged={this.handleArticleUpdate} />
```

But i receive the error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleArticleUpdate' of undefined

Comment: Can you share your code and specify the line that's throwing the error? From what you've shared so far the error is suggesting `this` is `undefined`, but it's hard to say what is happening without seeing how you have this structured.

Comment: Yes.. hard to predict the error here without look at the class. Mean time, you may try with bind your  function in the constructor..... this.handleArticleUpdate = this.handleArticleUpdate.bind(this);